# How to set up a file handler in code for all loggers?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

The logger definition for the `Base.class` looks like below. Here, a file handler is defined directly in the code.

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Base.class.getName());
/ * 
set file handler
*/
logger.addHandler(fileHandler); //just for `this` logger
```

When it comes to define a logger in another class, do I need to do everything with the file handler again (otherwise it won't write to the file)?

Comment: Most logging frameworks, including JUL, have some kind of "call the parent" concept. For example, if your class is `com.example.Base`, then the above will log to the "com.example.Base" logger, the "com.example" logger, the "com" logger, and the root logger (so long as each logger in the chain is [configured to use its parent handlers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Logger.html#setUseParentHandlers(boolean))). So, you could just add the file handler to the root logger or a common ancestor logger.

Comment: @Slaw could you provide an answer with code examples?

Comment: By default, every logger will call its parent handlers. At the start of your application, create your file handler and add it to the root logger. You can get the root logger with `Logger.getLogger("")`. If you do this then _do not_ add the file handler to your "base class logger", otherwise logging to the "base class logger" will cause the log to be output to the file twice.

Comment: Note you can use a properties file to configure the loggers or, if you want to do the configuration programmatically, consolidate the logic into its own class. See the Javadoc of [`LogManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) for more information.

Comment: @Slaw The reason I used configuration programmatically because of custom formatter to not include package name in logs. If there is a way to configure it in properties file, it would be nice to know it.